# XMasonry, XBlock (react-xmasonry) using as separate components: TypeError: this.props.parent is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use the npm modul react-xmasonry. When I implement the XMasonry, XBlock in one component, is's all fine. But when I try to separate them into two compoenents, I get the errors:

The `<t>` component is somewhere in the XBlock component

```
The above error occurred in the <t> component:
    in t (created by Message2)
    in Message2 (created by GridListPost1)
    in div (created by t)
    in t (created by GridListPost1)
    in GridListPost1 (created by Channel)
    in div (created by Channel)
    in div (created by Channel)
    in Channel (created by Connect(Channel))
    in Connect(Channel) (created by RouterContext)
    in div (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App (created by Connect(App))
    in Connect(App) (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in Router
    in Provider

TypeError: this.props.parent is undefined
```

Minimal example:

```
import { XMasonry } from "react-xmasonry";
import Message2 from '../message/Message2'

export default class GridListPost1 extends Component {

  render() {

    const {items} = this.props;

    return (
        <XMasonry>
          {items.map(message => (
            <Message2 key={message.id} message={message}/>
          ))}
        </XMasonry>
    )
  }
}


import { XBlock } from "react-xmasonry";

export default class Message2 extends Component {

  render() {

    const {message} = this.props;

    return (
        <XBlock key={message.id}>
          <div className="card">
                <h1>Wide Card</h1>
                <p>Put any wide text here!</p>
            </div>
        </XBlock>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see this.props.parent in your code? share your app.js file code

Comment: I provided it now but is the problem really somewhere there?

Comment: Are you accessing this.props.parent in anywhere in your components?

Comment: No, not myself. It looks like, that the XBlock is using it somehow. When I use the XMasonry and the XBlock in one react component, it works fine and no error. But when I separate them in two components, it doesn't work. But it's important for me, because every message has it's own states and so on.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you because I don't have idea about XMasonry and the XBlock these libraries. Interms of warning you need to add key as suggested in my answer and key should be unique otherwise only first element will be rendered

Comment: Yes, I added the key and the warning is gone. But error still there. I updated the error view. Maybe it's now more visible

Comment: Looks like <XBlock> must be enclosed inside <XMasonry>  and you can't use it seperately. It seems that's why it throws an error as this.props.parent undefined

Comment: Yes, exactly, when I would use it all in one component, I have to use array states and so on. That's not good, it will be much more complicated.

Comment: Here is a link to the component with description: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-xmasonry. There is a tab Reference. maybe this must be used somehow?

Comment: The library demands to have <XBlock> inside <XMasonry>. You have no other way except using as they suggested in the doc

Comment: OK, thx, this is really bad. Then I have to use all state as array.

Comment: Keeping an array in state and modifying is very easy in react. It's not that complex

Answer (score 0):

You need to add key prop to Message2 to fix the warning

```
     {items.map(message => (
        <Message2 key={message.id} message={message}/>
      ))}
```

OR if your items don't contain an id then add index as key like below

```
    {items.map((message, i) => (
        <Message2 key={i} message={message}/>
      ))}
```

Comment: Thx for fast response, but it's not the main problem. I still have the error TypeError: this.props.parent is undefined. So the error is coming from the XBlock somewhere